# Create your own Gym Exercise and follow along irl

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art, animation

Let's do an exercise together, shall we? Simply follow the movements of the stickman. What stickman you ask? The one we are about to create!

Make a program that allows for a string-input only containing integers, and outputs the following nine stick-figures with an interval in between:

```
 @  \@/ |@_ _@| @/   \@ |@| \@\ /@/
/|\  |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
/ \ / \ / \ / \ /|\ /|\ / \ / \ / \
 1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
```

This will result in an animation, which we can then follow along irl.

Here is an example of the output created when the input is "`123245762`":

[image]

**Some rules:**

- This is tagged [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest code in bytes wins
- The input is a `string` only containing `[1-9]` with a length potentially varying from 2 to 100 characters **
- The animation must be an endless loop
- The interval time must be 750 ms
- No duplicated adjacent integers are allowed in the input - this also includes the first and last integers of the input (see the seventh and eight test cases) **

** How it fails in case of invalid input is completely up to you, but **it should be clear that it fails**. It could throw an exception; simply return at the start; reboot your PC; delete it's own source-/compile-code; hack into the military and shoots a rocket to the compiling GPS-location. Your call. **EDIT:** It's not allowed to simply display a (correct / half) animation as failing input. It must be clear that something is wrong with the input for the failing testcases below. Thanks to *@user81655* for bringing this to my attention, hence the edit.

**Subrules:**

- Please post the gif for one of the (non-failing) test cases below in your answer, which you can make very easy with the following program: [screentogif.codeplex.com](https://screentogif.codeplex.com/) (Any other gif-creating program is also allowed of course.)
- ***Bonus points if you actually do the exercise alongside the animation irl when it's finished. ;)***

**Correct testcases:**

1. `123245762`
2. `65`
3. `121234346565879879132418791576`

**Failing testcases:**

4. `2` // Too few characters
5. `7282918274959292747383785189478174826894958127476192947512897571298593912374857471978269591928974518735891891723878` // Too much characters
6. `1232405762` // Containing invalid input (the `0`)
7. `112212` // Fails because of the `11` and `22` present
8. `1232457621` // Fails because of the starting and leading `1`

Comment: IMO this is a borderline dupe of [this](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/64349/194)

Comment: BTW, making edits after a challenge is posted is discouraged.

Comment: imo the input validation ruins the challenge.

Comment: @FlipTack You're indeed right. I should have just kept with the challenge and assume all input is valid. This was my very first question here on PPCG. Bit too late to change it now, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Pyth, 114 bytes

```
.V0j@cv.Z"xÚí» À0DW¹NM@+Üñ\">íÂA¸êÄÓw»`3±2þ&'NövfAé8é~0,p'ÆìÞúr_'¥,d!YÈBíéqs"3tv@zb.d.75
```

[image: Output GIF]

[Try it here](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=Vlzj%40cv.Z%22x%C3%9A%C3%AD%C2%8F%C2%BB%09%C3%800%0CDW%C2%B9NM%40%2B%C3%9C%1E%C2%91%C3%B1%5C%22%1A%3E%C2%8E%C3%AD%C3%82%01A%16%C2%B8%C3%AA%C3%84%C3%93%C2%8Fw%1B%08%C2%BB%60%C2%9E%113%C2%B12%C2%82%C3%BE%26%12%27N%C3%B6%C2%82vfA%C3%A98%C3%A9~0%C2%9A%2Cp%C2%96%27%C3%86%C3%AC%C3%9E%C3%BAr_%27%16%C2%9A%C2%A5%2Cd!%0BY%C3%88B%16%7F%16%C3%AD%01%1C%C3%A9qs%223tv%40zN&input=123245762&debug=0)

(No pausing, non-infinite)

Comment: Hmm, it isn't possible to return/throw or loop infinitely in Pyth? Or it will take too much bytes/is too time-consuming to make? (Currently it works the same for all correct testcases, as well as all failing testcases. And it also adds in the output for `0`.) Regardless, thanks for the entry. Definitely one of the most unreadable code-snippets for this entry is my guess. :)

Comment: The online interpreter doesn't flush IO during a sleep so it isn't noticed. You did say you wanted an infinite loop so I'm not sure what you're asking there. "How it fails is up to you" - I'm doing undefined behavior for this; the code might do anything (even though it SHOULD behave the same) Also I'm expecting this to be relatively readable compared to some possible entries

Answer (score 4):

## SpecBAS - 387 bytes

```
1 DIM m$=" @"#13"/|\"#13"/ \","\@/"#13" |"#13"/ \","|@_"#13" |"#13"/ \","_@|"#13" |"#13"/ \","@/"#13" |"#13"/|\"," \@"#13" |"#13"/|\","|@|"#13" |"#13"/ \","\@\"#13" |"#13"/ \","/@/"#13" |"#13"/ \"
2 INPUT a$: o=0
3 IF LEN a$<2 OR LEN a$>100 THEN 10
4 FOR i=1 TO LEN a$
5 n=VAL(a$(i))
6 IF n=0 OR n=o THEN 10
7 CLS : ?m$(n): o=n: WAIT 750
8 NEXT i
9 GO TO 4
10 CLS : ?" @"#13"-O-"#13"/ \"#13"FAT"
```

Keeps looping until you press ESC. Failure to exercise properly (incorrect input - in this example a 0 as one of the steps) leads to fatness. The GIF loops, in the program it just stops at that point.

`#13` is the SpecBAS equivalent to `\n` and lets you include line feed in strings.

[image]

Comment: "FAT" :D ......

Answer (score 2):

### JavaScript (ES6), 165 bytes

```js
f=s=>{n=s[0];e.textContent=' @ \\@/|@__@|@/  \\@|@|\\@\\/@/'.substr(n*3-3,3)+(n>1?`
 | 
`:`
/|\\
`)+(n<5|n>6?'/ \\':'/|\\');s=s.slice(1)+n;s[0]-n&&setTimeout(f,750,s)}
f("123245762")
```

```html
<pre id=e>
```

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES6), 210 bytes

```js
s=>setInterval(_=>(c=console).clear(i=0)&c.log(`, @
/|\\
/ \\,\\@/
 |
/ \\,|@_
 |
/ \\,_@|
 |
/ \\,@/
 |
/|\\, \\@
 |
/|\\,|@|
 |
/ \\,\\@\\
 |
/ \\,/@/
 |
/ \\`.split`,`[s[i++%s.length]]),750)
```

Comment: How does this handle the rules about excluding `0` and duplicates?

Comment: @Morgan'Venti'Thrappuccino I was under the impression that invalid inputs don't need defined behaviour, since it says `How it fails in case of invalid input is completely up to you`. I just handle invalid input by displaying an animation. :P None of the other existing answers checked this either, however the answer the OP just posted does, so maybe he did want us to handle invalid input.

Comment: "I just handle invalid input by displaying an animation. :P" Lol.. That's one way of looking at it. xD I'll edit the question.

Answer (score 1):

## Java 8, <s>663</s> <s>636</s> <s>634</s> <s>631</s> <s>596</s> <s>355</s> <s>354</s> 343 bytes

Just for the lols I tried to make the program in Java. <s>Admittedly I'm pretty bad at golfing and regexes, so it can most likely be golfed (a lot?) more. Nevertheless, here it is in Java 7.</s>
Now almost two years later and I almost halved the code in Java 8. Why did I ever made those rules about validating the input and requiring a full program, though... >.> I hate my past self now..

```java
interface M{static void main(String[]a)throws Exception{for(;a[0].matches("[1-9]{2,100}")&!a[0].matches(".*(.)\\2.*|(.).*\\1");)for(int c:a[0].getBytes()){c-=48;System.out.printf("%s%n%s%n%s%n",c<2?" @ ":c<3?"\\@/":c<4?"|@_":c<5?"_@|":c<6?"@/ ":c<7?" \\@":c<8?"|@|":c<9?"\\@\\":"/@/",c<2?"/|\\":" | ",c%7>4?"/|\\":"/ \\");Thread.sleep(750);}}}
```

-11 bytes thanks to *@ceilingcat*.

**Explanation:**

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##VY/RboIwFIZfpTuJCzVSoKKouEGW7HJX7s4S05SiuFkIdG4GeHZWWLZkF02@/Oc7f07P/MrtopTqnL71fa60rDIuJHppas11LtC1yFN04bmydrrK1XGfcKxPVfFZo@cvIUudF6rJisoK@d5NyIVrcZK1BXvPXicNnXmu2wG@v/s/JVOLYMYombYGyJQxD3CIhx5zAxKbUT9K/XTTxse4EfaDvwp3t1rLCyk@NCnNNTqzYFJP1O@DmdjSCFCMYCO28wgYi50B/Qja@DDQIoJD3A60jCB2RjEwK8YccDWI43g9bjMGG3BMyU@z044BapEJJsGj/xc5psF84fVUSZ6S@l3K0goWLg67ruv73qNz6i@CJf0G) (After it has timed out after 60 sec.)

```java
interface M{                     // Class
  static void main(String[]a)    //  Mandatory main-method
      throws Exception{          //    Required throws for the `Thread.sleep`
    for(;a[0].matches("[1-9]{2,100}")
                                 //   Validate 2-100 integers only containing 1-9
         &!a[0].matches(".*(.)\\2.*|(.).*\\1")
                                 //   Validate no adjacent duplicated char (with wrap-around)
        ;)                       //   And start an infinite loop if it's valid:
      for(int c:a[0].getBytes()){//    Inner loop over the characters of the input:
        c-=48;                   //     Convert the character-code to an integer
        System.out.printf("%s%n%s%n%s%n",
                                 //     Print:
          c<2?" @ ":c<3?"\\@/":c<4?"|@_":c<5?"_@|":c<6?"@/ ":c<7?" \\@":c<8?"|@|":c<9?"\\@\\":"/@/",
                                 //      The top part of the stick figure
          c<2?"/|\\":" | ",      //      The middle part of the stick figure
          c%7>4?"/|\\":"/ \\");  //      The bottom part of the stick figure
        Thread.sleep(750);}}}    //     Sleep 750 ms
```

**Gif:**
*(Note: Old gif, since it's clearly jdk1.8+ now.)*

[image]

Comment: Usually we say `Java 7` to refer to this version of Java as `1.7` can confuse some to think that it is `Java 1` revision `7`

Comment: The long if statement could be turned into something like `p(new String[]{" @ ",y,"|@_", ... }[c-49]);if(c==49){p(x);l();}else if(c==53){w();p(x);}else d();`. Also I think that defining `l` and `w` wastes characters, now that they're only used twice. Consider letting `s` instead be `char[] s=a[0].toCharArray()`; all the other operations with it are much shorter, then.

Answer (score 0):

## Mathematica, 252 bytes

```
i=0;Dynamic[Uncompress["1:eJxTTMoPSuNkYGAoZgESPpnFJcFCQIaCQ4yBoZF+TUwMmFaIiQELx8Q46IMEFGrgwoJA4RqHeCyi8Q41aKICQFEUA2qg5gIlHdCEIeaimyAMcQTEWWj26aO7DQDaqDEh"][[FromDigits[#~StringTake~{i=i~Mod~StringLength@#+1}]]],UpdateInterval->3/4,TrackedSymbols->{}]&
```

Would be nice if someone could create a GIF. Run in a notebook.

Answer (score 0):

## Python3, 338 bytes

```
import os,time
p=" @ \n/|\\\n/ \\","\\@/\n | \n/ \\","|@_\n | \n/ \\","_@|\n | \n/ \\","@/ \n | \n/|\\"," \\@\n | \n/|\\","|@|\n | \n/ \\","\\@\\\n | \n/ \\","/@/\n | \n/ \\"
i=input()
for j in range(len(i)):(i[j]in"123456789"and i[j]!=i[(j+1)%len(i)])or exit()
while 1:[[time.sleep(0.75),os.system("clear"),print(p[int(j)-1])]for j in i]
```