# Make a hammer animation

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art, kolmogorov-complexity, animation

The goal is to make a two frame animation with ASCII art of a hammer smacking a table.

Trailing white-space is allowed and the frames need to repeat continuously. The program should iterate over both frames with a time of 0.5 seconds between frames.

Lowest byte count wins for each language!

**Sample:**

Animation Frames:

```
Frame 1:
 -------------------
|                   |
|                   |
|                   |
 -------------------         
         /  /
        /  /
       /  /
      /  /
     /  /
    /  /
   /  /
  /  /
 /  /
 \ /                              


                        ---------------------------
                       |                           |


Frame 2:

                                        ----------
                                       |          |
                                       |          |
                                       |          |
 --------------------------------------|          |
|                                      |          |
 --------------------------------------|          |
                                       |          |
                                       |          |
                                       |          |
                                        ----------
                                  -------------------------------
                                |                                |
```

Comment: Welcome to the site! This sounds like a good idea, but you need to be way more specific, and spell out what the anination should be like. See other challenges in the [tag:ascii-art] or [tag:animation] tags for reference

Comment: @LuisMendo Is This Better?

Comment: @PythonDude29 If the answer needs to be a program/function which takes a number (say 1/2 or 0/1) and produces the appropriate frame, then you need to state so. If frame 1 needs to be displayed and then exchanged for frame 2 after a predetermined time or event, you need to state so.

Comment: You also need to clarify if trailing whitespace is acceptable.

Comment: I think I am Done.

Comment: @Scrooble Is that everything? Or is there more specifics I need

Comment: I'm not a fan of these line controllers—it is my understanding that languages like Charcoal don't operate that way. I'd refer to other [tag:ascii-art] and [tag:kolmogorov-complexity] questions. However, this challenge does now fall within this site's requirements (IMO), so I'm voting to reopen.

Comment: @Scrooble Hmm I only know a couple languages. I know Python, A Bit Of JavaScript And A bit Of C#. I used the line controllers when I did my own(Where I got the idea)

Comment: Must the font be monospace? Is graphical output allowed?

Comment: Also please don't write in title case.

Comment: Doesn't this pretty much end up as run length encoding in just about every language?

Comment: This is kinda a combination of [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/101289/loading-forever?rq=1) and most ascii art with high repetition/run length, but i'm not sure if it should be considered a duplicate.

Comment: @fəˈnɛtɪk I think it's more [like this one](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/64349/get-happy-and-mad), then the one you linked. That one also replaces the current ASCII art at every iteration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), <strike>391 355 293 286</strike> 296 bytes

Whack whack whack, golfing those chars off, down to 296 b :)
.5s sleep as per the question specs.

This also requires perl -E

```
$r="| 19|n"x 3;$p="| 10|n";$R=" 39$p"x 3;$T=" -38$p";$t=" 40-10n";$m=" -19n$r -19n 9H 8H 7H 6H 5H 4H 3H 2H 2\\ /n3 24-27n 23| 27|n";$M="$t$R$T| 38$p$T$R$t 34-30n 33| 30|n";for($m){say"\033[2J";map{s:H:/  /n:;y!n!\n!;print$1x($2?$2:1)if/(\D+)(\d*)/}(split/(.\d*)/);($m,$M)=($M,$m);select$v,$V,$v,.5;redo}
```

Explanation/comments:

```
# initial vars build strings that the print will understand later
$r="| 19|n"x 3;
$p="| 10|n";
$R=" 39$p"x 3;
$T=" -38$p";
$t=" 40-10n";

# set $_ to first frame
$_=" -19n$r -19n 9H 8H 7H 6H 5H 4H 3H 2H 2\\ /n3 24-27n 23| 27|n";

# M is second frame
$M="$t$R$T| 38$p$T$R$t 34-30n 33| 30|n";

# main loop
{

# clear screen
say"\033[2J";

# or windows, -1b
# system"cls";

# start map...
map{

# sed replace H for /  /n
s:H:/  /n:;

# tr replace n for newline
y!n!\n!;

# parens around ?: necessary due to x operator precedence
# if/regex/ prints $1 $2 times 
print$1x($2?$2:1)if/(\D+)(\d*)/

# map runs on char followed by a number or not
}(split/(.\d*)/);

# rotate frames
($_,$M)=($M,$_);

# sleep for 1 second would be shorter, but perl does
# not deal with integer sleep without time::hires
# sleep 1;

# select for decimal second sleep
select$v,$v,$v,.5;

# do the current block again
redo
}
```

GIF of original in action:
[image: in action]

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! It's common courtesy to have a header with the language name and byte count. Hope you stick around!

Comment: Thanks, I missed adding the title the first time through.

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>337</s>  <s>331</s> 319 bytes

-12 bytes thanks to Amphibological

```python
import os,time
t,e,q,p='- \n|'
j=e+t*19+q
L=p+e*19+p+q
l=j+3*L+j
for i in range(9):l+=e*(9-i)+'/  /'+q
l+=' \\ /'+3*q+e*24+t*27+q+e*23+p+27*e+p+q
c=39*e
C=p+10*e+p+q
m=10*t+q
R=e+38*t+C
f=(c+C)*3
r=q+c+e+m+f+R+p+38*e+C+R+f+c+e+m+34*e+31*t+q+32*e+p+32*e+q
b=0
while 1:print([r,l][b]);time.sleep(.5);os.system('cls');b=~b
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LZA9b4MwEIZ3/wpvNj5CAk6VEuSJNVPWJENBR2PEh8GWqkhV/zo9UKZ77tWr5yy7V3iOg14W27txDnz0cbA9shBjPMXOiB2/D7@CtQYhqDSHiV2MA1zR0dKZFrS6QMuaceaW24HPX8M3yjw6d2BQyXxnIxB7zvdi7YMR/H5fF60m8mRH8mYn2FiTMzsp3NS10blCVtK59PDOekMYCK70Hv1JWLLGyBrKSGk2mwlqQOihgSv1qYBQEjbvWB8p0OlqAJ1tzm1MrDIH9vO0HfL07GY7BHmb4@5xqx5RsX5I4jtEJ5OPqBh94l8@YC9F3XkRFZX5q5blHw)

It uses 'cls', so will only work on Windows, use 'clear' for Linux with +2 bytes.

Will add a gif later.

Comment: Nice! You could change `r if b else l` to `[r,l][b]`  and `import os\nimport time` to `import os,time` to save some bytes.

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3.6](https://www.python.org/), [413 bytes](https://ethproductions.github.io/bytes/?e=ascii&t=from%20os%20import%2A%0Afrom%20time%20import%2A%0As%2Cy%3D%27%20-%27%3Bb%3Dy%2A19%3Bd%3Db%2Bb%3Bf%3Dy%2A10%3Bi%3Dy%2A26%3Bg%3Ds%2A9%3Bc%3Ds%2Bg%3Bh%3Ds%2A26%3Bj%3Ds%2A32%3Ba%3Dc%2Bg%3Be%3Da%2Ba%3Bp%3Dprint%3Bk%3Df%27%5Cn%7C%7Ba%7D%7C%27%3Bt%2Cv%3Dsystem%2Csleep%3Bz%3D%27cls%27%0Awhile%201%3A%0A%20t%28z%29%3Bp%28f%27%20%7Bb%7D%20%7Bk%2A3%7D%5Cn%20%7Bb%7D%27%29%0A%20for%20x%20in%20range%289%29%3Ap%28f%27%7Bg%5Bx%3A%5D%7D%2F%20%20%2F%27%29%0A%20p%28f%27%20%5C%5C%20%2F%5Cn%20%7Ba%7D%20%7Bi%7D%5Cn%20%7Ba%7D%7C%7Bh%7D%7C%27%29%3Bv%281%29%3Bt%28z%29%3Bp%28f%27%20%7Be%7D%20%7Bf%7D%27%29%0A%20for%20w%20in%20range%287%29%3Ap%28f%27%20%7Be%7D%7C%7Bc%7D%7C%27%29if%20w!%3D3else%20p%28f%27%20%7Bd%7D%7C%7Bc%7D%7C%5Cn%7C%7Be%7D%7C%7Bc%7D%7C%5Cn%20%7Bd%7D%7C%7Bc%7D%7C%27%29%0A%20p%28f%27%20%7Be%7D%20%7Bf%7D%5Cn%20%7Bj%7D%20%7Bi%7D%5Cn%20%7Bj%7D%7C%7Bh%7D%7C%27%29%3Bv%281%29)

```
from os import*
from time import*
s,y=' -';b=y*19;d=b+b;f=y*10;i=y*26;g=s*9;c=s+g;h=s*26;j=s*32;a=c+g;e=a+a;p=print;k=f'\n|{a}|';t,v=system,sleep;z='cls'
while 1:
 t(z);p(f' {b} {k*3}\n {b}')
 for x in range(9):p(f'{g[x:]}/  /')
 p(f' \\ /\n {a} {i}\n {a}|{h}|');v(1);t(z);p(f' {e} {f}')
 for w in range(7):p(f' {e}|{c}|')if w!=3else p(f' {d}|{c}|\n|{e}|{c}|\n {d}|{c}|')
 p(f' {e} {f}\n {j} {i}\n {j}|{h}|');v(1)
```

Doesn't work on TIO, so here's a GIF:

[image: Hammer ASCIIMation]

Not the prettiest thing in the world, but I'm pretty proud of it. Suggestions on golfing it further are welcome!

P.S.: I used a 1 second delay because it looked better to me, but you can replace `1` with `.5` to change that, at +2 bytes.

P.P.S: This will only work on Windows, to try on Unix, change `cls` to `clear` at +2 bytes.

Comment: That's as amazing how does it work how long did it take you

Comment: @PythonDude29 thanks. It didn't take too long, maybe about 45 mins. It works mostly by substituting variables into strings with the new python f-strings. I'll post a more detailed explanation when I get a chance.

Comment: Ok it's really cool

Comment: @PythonDude29 thanks. I really appreciate it!