# ASCII Pumpkin Carving

Tags: code-golf, string, ascii-art

Today is Halloween and it's time to carve some pumpkins!

```
   &
((^.^))
```

Given an input integer, string, list of integers, etc., output the corresponding pumpkin. The input will always be of the form `Stem, Eyes, Mouth, Width`. For example, `2331` would be a valid input.

The pumpkin takes the form:

```
   S
((EME))
```

where `S` is the stem, `E` are the eyes, `M` is the mouth, and the parens form the body.

#### Definitions

Stem:
`0` for a curl `&`
`1` for a straight `|`
`2` for a slant left `\`
`3` for a slant right `/`

Eyes:
`0` for angled `^`
`1` for small dots `.`
`2` for medium dots `o`
`3` for large dots `O`

Mouth:
`0` for angled `v`
`1` for small dot `.`
`2` for medium dot `o`
`3` for large dot `O`

Width:
`0` for a skinny pumpkin (only one pair of parens)
`1` for a fat pumpkin (two pairs of parens)

#### Examples

```
0011
   &
((^.^))

3100
   /
 (.v.)

2331
   \
((OOO))

1200
   |
 (ovo)
```

### Rules

- Input/output can be given by [any convenient method](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/2447/42963).
- You can print it to STDOUT or return it as a function result.
- Either a full program or a function are acceptable.
- Any amount of extraneous whitespace is permitted, provided the characters line up appropriately.
- You must use the numbering and ordering of the pumpkin carvings as they are described above.
- [Standard loopholes](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/1061/42963) are forbidden.
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so all usual golfing rules apply, and the shortest code (in bytes) wins.

Comment: Quite similar to [Do you want to code a snowman?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/49671/do-you-want-to-code-a-snowman).

Comment: @manatwork Hmm, that is kinda similar. I'll leave it up to the community to determine if that's a dupe target or not.

Answer (score 5):

## [Add++](https://github.com/cairdcoinheringaahing/AddPlusPlus), 56 bytes

```
L,"&|\/^.oOv.oO ((("4$Tz£:BF"("+@32C3*$+Bh$2D-1A:1+")"*J
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0xJKSj4/99HR0mtJkY/Ti/fvwyIFTQ0NJRMVEKqDi22cnJT0lDSdjA2cjbWUtF2ylAxctE1dLQy1FbSVNLy@q@Sk5iblJKoYGgXbaRgDISGsVz@XEiihgpGCgYKBkDR/wA)

Add++ is not the best at string manipulation challenges

### How it works

We create an lambda function that takes a single argument - a list of integers - and outputs the final pumpkin.

```
L,                    - Define our function. Takes in a four element list e.g. [0 0 1 1]
                                                       STACK = [[0 0 1 1]]
  "&|\/^.oOv.oO ((("  - Push this string               STACK = [[0 0 1 1] '&|\/^.oOv.oO (((']
  4$T                 - Split it into 4 pieces         STACK = [[0 0 1 1] ['&|\/' '^.oO' 'v.oO' ' (((']
  z                   - Zip the lists together         STACK = [[['&|\\/' 0] ['^.oO' 0] ['v.oO' 1] [' (((' 1]]]
  £:                  - Index into each string         STACK = [['&' '^' '.' '(']]
  BF                  - Flatten the stack              STACK = ['&' '^' '.' '(']
  "("+                - Append a "(" to last element   STACK = ['&' '^' '.' '((']
  @                   - Reverse stack                  STACK = ['((' '.' '^' '&']
  32C3*$+             - Prepend 3 spaces to stalk      STACK = ['((' '.' '^' '   &']
  Bh                  - Output stack with newline      STACK = ['((' '.' '^']
  $2D                 - Push from under                STACK = ['((' '^' '.' '^']
  -1A:1+              - Add one the the last argument  STACK = ['((' '^' '.' '^' 2]
  ")"*                - Repeat ")" that many times     STACK = ['((' '^' '.' '^' '))']
  J                   - Join together                  STACK = ['((^.^))']
                      - Implicitly output
```

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript (ES6), 78 bytes

```javascript
(s,e,m,w)=>`   ${'&|\\/'[s]}
${' ('[w]}(${(e='^.oO'[e])+'v.oO'[m]+e})`+' )'[w]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dYtNDoIwEIX3nGIWxOmkI/Kzxit4AKiBYDESoMYaWCBnr5WdC/I27@X7XldPtW1ej@f7OJqbdm3uhGXNA8@UnysACBc8fMryhIVVa@AXCCxmtYpwETrHa2QuWGhFEqetDkrqlSqJQD/PNWa0ptdRb@6iFTHHnHBCIAHLESn4x5mHXtnDKWc@u@@E0@1N7gs)

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>96</s> <s>87</s> <s>86</s> 84 bytes

```python
lambda s,e,m,w,a="^.oO":" "*(2+w)+"&|\/"[s]+"\n"+"("*-~w+a[e]+"v.oO"[m]+a[e]+")"*-~w
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUaFYJ1UnV6dcJ9FWKU4v31/JSklBSUvDSLtcU1tJrSZGXym6OFZbKSZPSVtJQ0lLt65cOzE6FShSBlIcnRsL5WqC5f4XFGXmlWikaRjoGIKgpiYXTMQYyDfQMUASMdIxBkJkNYY6RhA1/wE)

Thanks to:
- [@79037662](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/89930/79037662) for saving me 2 bytes

Comment: Is the ```1*``` necessary in ```(2+1*w)```?

Comment: @79037662 no :D thanks, i didn't see it when i changed it...

Answer (score 1):

## [Wren](https://github.com/munificent/wren), <del>98</del> 90 bytes

A naive approach. I could have used a lookup table, it golfs out 8 bytes.

```
Fn.new{|a,b,c,d|" "*3+"&|\\/"[a]+"\n"+" ("[d]+"("+"^.oO"[b]+"v.oO"[c]+"^.oO"[b]+")"*(d+1)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY2xDsIgFAB/hbzBQHlBGmdXVwdHqAkFTEzqa4K1xIjfjujkdnfL5RSpri6xy4M829cDKYr5VRyO6DEUYNDtJGyKtVswbpBgCSQwDiY04Y3Paj6CGZutP/LDfxPQ8SB78a6n532JN5XTdYn8u1PeTRPXqLFHLUT9AA)

## [Wren](https://github.com/munificent/wren), <del>148</del> 144 bytes

An even worse solution, yet I'd like to share it. Does a bunch of replaces on the specified string

```
Fn.new{|a,b,c,d|"   S\nW(EME)w".replace("S","&|\\/"[a]).replace("W"," ("[d]).replace("w"," )"[d]).replace("E","^.oO"[b]).replace("M","v.oO"[c])}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Xc4xDsIgFADQq5A/GEh@sLo74tY4MHSAmlCKiUlFg7XEiGdH6mLj@qYXg/N5MoGcHt6SXd577l18JYMdWuwTEEKk9g0VtWAReHC3wVhHQQLCKmm9BmVa9vOmOKGg@iXGGdkfioJHfj2A6pZcF56@bFv2zvJ5H92Fx3AeHZ2T3JphoBvcYoUVY/kD)

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 28 bytes

```
↙§&|\/Ｎ§^.oOＮ←§v.oOＮ←←×(⊕Ｎ‖Ｂ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMPKJb88zyc1rURHwbHEMy8ltUJDSa0mJkZfSUfBM6@gtMSvNDcptUhDU1PTmguiBa4uTi/fH7cyKzRTy3Co9s0vS4UoRtcakpmbWqyhpAHWlVyUmpuaV5KaooFmAlBXUGpaTmpyiVNpSUlqUVpOpYam9f//xlyGXAZcBv91y3IA) Link is to verbose version of code. Taking the inputs in a better order would save 2 bytes. Explanation:

```
↙§&|\/Ｎ
```

Input the stem and output the appropriate character, then move to the left eye.

```
§^.oOＮ
```

Input the eyes and output the appropriate character.

```
←§v.oOＮ←
```

Input the nose and output the appropriate character, then move to the left of the left eye.

```
←×(⊕Ｎ
```

Input the width and output the appropriate number of `(`s.

```
‖Ｂ
```

Reflect to complete the pumpkin.

Answer (score 0):

## [PHP](https://php.net/) (7.4), 91 bytes

Generates the output string using a template string and `strtr` array replacement mode.

```php
fn($s,$e,$m,$w)=>strtr('   0
3(121)4',['&|\/'[$s],'^.oO'[$e],'v.oO'[$m],' ('[$w],' )'[$w]])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY3BDoIwDIbve4qGLG5LKjLwhuAj@ACACSFb4CAQRvSgPjuWge3l@/u3f8d2XC7XsR0Z4zZbbC@5Q26QP5C/VJa7eZonKQAgYonUsVZngYU4fMqTKLirUNzD4UZoCJ8bPghBErxWUB4qtaT0YjZudpBBwSixiDBCjbpCrxJimuwqxoT672mMd6@iGDtMpm5akHte7YB3kOXgtYL3egOdpYVOgWnaAYKyL/vjVisGqd/xHrcyDMPtNmXf5Qc)

---

## [PHP](https://php.net/) (7.4), 93 bytes

Generates the output string as it goes on.

```php
fn($s,$e,$m,$w)=>'   '.'&|\/'[$s].'
'.' ('[$w].'('.($y='^.oO'[$e]).'v.oO'[$m]."$y)".' )'[$w];
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY1NbsIwEIX3PsUoGtW2NEwJLIPhCD1A4koI2UoW@RFGIER79nRwUnvzvnlv3kztNB9OUzsphdHNcTCYCANhT/iw7qgBQLP@@Gk@dY3Js1aCYAQeAkazwafT3zx@ySh4y/q@6N5zgU9bSNrmdDVXcuQW0i2Bg1pJc72lLZVUesq0Fy2TlXa0l//vlbRbPS81cbyG86UFs/adE2AH7giZLbzeO9BFCXQWwqUdoWiGZtgs7y2LKmeyh9Ew87Jbqd/5Dw)

Answer (score 0):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), 135 bytes

```
func[s e m w][a:["&|\/""^^.oO""v.oO"" ("" )"]rejoin["   "a/1/(s + 1) lf a/4/(t: w + 1) "("a/2/(u: e + 1) a/3/(m + 1) a/2/:u ")"a/5/:t]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYzNCsIwEITvfYphD5IiuKbVS15C8BpTCDaBirbSH3vx3eNSqciyy8w3w/ahTudQW5dl0aQ4tVc7IOCB2VlvLG3eFyaqql13InotF0o2J9eHW9e0lgCQZ81qwBY6xz3C84HVaDB/CSkpFKwmI68X4rlk9Vh1wWYC5VI6shmdS8@@aUdE7GU0dLb6Upywny@ElH@5FiJ5@gA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Icon](https://github.com/gtownsend/icon), 121 bytes

```
procedure f(s,e,m,w)
return map("   s\nw(eme)u","semwu","&|\\/"[s+1]||"^.oO"[e+1]||"v.oO"[m+1]||" ("[w+1]||" )"[w+1])
end
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY2xDoMwDER3vsLyUDmq1RL4kH4AtBICIzEkoASahX@noWFokYe7dz7phna02za5sZVucQI9eRY2HFTmZF6cBdNMhADgaxtIjKgFGb2YsOtlres7Vv6qn@uKr9v4wEoSvL9gEgBhFQ6rklWZ2O5n2TSDJZXFJQhumIV6yjlnzVr9p2XM4ueUFlzGO3c1F0d3H/sA)